# Tidyverse method for combining sets of columns based on a condition in the column names

Tags: r

Imagine I have the following columns (among others) in my dataframe (credit to Allan for creating the sample data):

```
20L, 15L), b_years = c(4L, 5L, 3L), b_months = 0:2, b_days = c(10L, 
8L, 6L), c_years = 8:6, c_months = c(11L, 9L, 8L), c_days = c(26L, 
19L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df
#>   a_years a_months a_days b_years b_months b_days c_years c_months c_days
#> 1       5        6     23       4        0     10       8       11     26
#> 2       4        7     20       5        1      8       7        9     19
#> 3       3        8     15       3        2      6       6        8     18
```

And I want to combine columns that start with the same grouping key (in this case the letter at the beginning, but in my data it's a longer expression) such that I get columns `a_days, b_days, c_days` and so on with values in eahc column equal to `x_years * 365 + x_months * 30 + x_days`, for each group (`a, b, c, d, e` and so on) of columns.

Is there a way to accomplish this all at once? Some combination of `map()` and `mutate()` comes to mind, or maybe using `case_when()`, but I can't quite figure it out. Thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Comment: Try:`library(dplyr) your_dataframe %>% select(contains("days")`

Comment: You should give us some rows of your input data, best use  `dput(head(name_of_your_dataframe))` and then you should also show how your desired output looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `across` inside `transmute`:

```r
library(dplyr)


df %>% 
  transmute(across(contains("days"),   ~ .x)      +
            across(contains("months"), ~ .x * 30) +
            across(contains("years"),   ~ .x * 365)) 
#>   a_days b_days c_days
#> 1   2028   1470   3276
#> 2   1690   1863   2844
#> 3   1350   1161   2448
```

---

**Sample data**

```r
df <- structure(list(a_years = 5:3, a_months = 6:8, a_days = c(23L, 
20L, 15L), b_years = c(4L, 5L, 3L), b_months = 0:2, b_days = c(10L, 
8L, 6L), c_years = 8:6, c_months = c(11L, 9L, 8L), c_days = c(26L, 
19L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df
#>   a_years a_months a_days b_years b_months b_days c_years c_months c_days
#> 1       5        6     23       4        0     10       8       11     26
#> 2       4        7     20       5        1      8       7        9     19
#> 3       3        8     15       3        2      6       6        8     18
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but I don't think I was clear enough in my question (my apologies). I want it to calculate the number of days within each group of columns (a, b, c) by combining the years, months and days variables.

So, using your sample data as an example, the first element of a_days would be 2,028 (5 years * 365 + 6 months * 30 + 23 days).

I should also mention that my actual data has like 15 different groups of columns, not three like in my example.

Comment: @daltoncito5034 yes, I know - that was just due to a typo. Now fixed. This should work with any number of groups of volumns as long as the naming is consistent and none of the groups are missing.